# PrimeFaces p:column filter facet not displayed

Tags: primefaces, primefaces-datatable

I have this PrimeFaces (4.0) table:

```
<p:dataTable id="datalist" widgetVar="datalist"
             value="#{hoursController.lazy}"
             lazy="true"
             filteredValue="#{hoursController.filteredItems}"
             var="item"
             selectionMode="single" selection="#{hoursController.selected}"
             rowKey="#{item.id}"
             paginator="true" paginatorPosition="bottom"
             rows="10"
             sortBy="workDate" sortOrder="descending">
```

With this column containing a `filter` facet (trying to replicate the brands filter in the [PrimeFaces DataTable filter showcase](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/filter.xhtml)):

```
<p:column headerText="#{msg.table_header_hours_emplId}"
          sortBy="#{item.emplId}"
          filterBy="#{item.emplId}" filterMatchMode="exact">
  <f:facet name="filter">
    <p:selectOneMenu onchange="PF('datalist').filter()">
      <f:selectItem itemLabel="" itemValue="#{null}" noSelectionOption="true" />
      <f:selectItems value="#{employeesController.items}" />
    </p:selectOneMenu>
  </f:facet>
  <h:outputText value="#{item.emplId}" />
</p:column>
```

The `p:selectOneMenu` is not displayed, but instead I just get a plain text input filter.

I removed all kinds of attributes from the table (lazy loading for example) to see if they were causing the filter not to be rendered, but all with the same result.

I'm also sure the `p:selectOneMenu` is correct; when I place it outside of the table it select menu is displaying the correct content.

I've also checked the specification on extra information on the `filter` facet, but could find any additional information.

Can anybody tell what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently [the `filter` facet was added in PrimeFaces 5](http://blog.primefaces.org/?p=3084) (so it does not work in 4). This was not mentioned in the documentation and showcase.